# What focal length is best for photography of rugs?

Tags: lens, focal-length, image-quality, product-photography, sony-alpha

What focal length is best for photography of rugs? I am choosing between a Sony 16-50mm lens and a 50-210mm lens.
Rugs size small and medium sized 2x3m
Notes :i have 2 only lenses size 16:50 mm and 50:210mm

Comment: How big are your rugs? What constraints do you have on where you can mount the camera?

Comment: Do you want to take photos of the whole rug from a shorter distance? From a longer distance? Or closeups to show small details of the rugs?

Comment: Related questions: [What is the best techniques to photograph large rugs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47551/what-is-the-best-techniques-to-photograph-large-rugs), [How do I set up my studio for shooting large rugs from the ceiling?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57135/how-do-i-set-up-my-studio-for-shooting-large-rugs-from-the-ceiling), probably more I haven't found yet.

Comment: Rugs size 2x3m in room at studio, and yes I'll take a photos of whole rug and some from a shorter distance for focus on fabric and details

Comment: If you already have both lenses, why not try them? A lot of it is going to be dependent on how far away from them you can get. The further away you are, the 'flatter' you can get the resulting image.

Comment: I'll try both in my home, before going to start rugs photoshoots for my client. THANKS @Tetsujin

Comment: Also related: [Taking pictures of rugs for online use](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/76310/15871)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a camera and a lens. Try them.

But the real answer depends on the relation between the size of the object you are photographing and the available space you have to move further back or not.

The "Best" focal length is normally the longest you can afford for the available space. This way you will reduce the perspective distortions.

And this distance depends on... Friction. Let me explain.

1. Imagine you can put a rough on a plywood table of 3m. (If you do not have it you probably need to construct it)
2. A good option is to incline that table to a degree that the rough does not bend to gravity.

[image]

3. If you manage to incline it further, without the rough slipping you have more space.

[image]

4. Probably, depending on the setup a zoom lens is a good option. So you have the flexibility to frame different sizes of roughs.

If your rough is 3m and you have a distance of 3m, more or less [your focal length is around 40mm on a full frame lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76041/how-can-i-explain-focal-length-to-someone-who-isnt-into-photography/76088#76088).

---

Use rough plywood, not the ones with shiny polished painted surfaces, so you maximize friction.

You could even paste some sandpaper into it.

---

So, again. Try the lenses you already have, with the space you have.